# What does $1 mean in JAVA?

Tags: java, jetty

Here is a shell script:

```
echo Starting Jarvis Program D.
ALICE_HOME=.
SERVLET_LIB=lib/servlet.jar
ALICE_LIB=lib/aliceserver.jar
JS_LIB=lib/js.jar

# Set SQL_LIB to the location of your database driver.
SQL_LIB=lib/mysql_comp.jar

# These are for Jetty; you will want to change these if you are using a different http server.
 HTTP_SERVER_LIBS=lib/org.mortbay.jetty.jar

 PROGRAMD_CLASSPATH=$SERVLET_LIB:$ALICE_LIB:$JS_LIB:$SQL_LIB:$HTTP_SERVER_LIBS
 java -classpath $PROGRAMD_CLASSPATH -Xms64m -Xmx128m org.alicebot.server.net.AliceServer $1
```

On the last line: what does the $1 mean??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question until you provide some real, actionable information and a true description as to what you problem is.  You misunderstanding of what arguments mean to a script is a red herring.

Comment: Ok I understand. I'm on my iPhone now so I will edit the question later tonight.

Comment: You can close it, I can't delete it now...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not Java, it's the shell scripting language. `$1` is the first argument supplied on the command line.  It tells the script to pass the first command line argument that you gave along to java.exe.  It, in turn, with be the first argument in your call to main().

If your main looked like this, and the value you supplied was "foo", the output would be "foo":

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    for (String arg : args)
    {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the name of the script is jarvis.sh, and you start it in a command shell by typing "jarvis.sh foo", then the first argument is "foo".

Comment: What is the problem?  You're asking a new question: "What does it mean to pass an argument into the shell I posted?"  Could you please edit your original question to provide more context and clarity as to the exact problem?

Answer (score 2):

`$1` in shell scriping means "argument number 1 passed to this shell script".

For instance, if you have a shell script called "foo.sh", with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1"
```

and you called it with `./foo.sh hello world`, then `hello` is the first argument passed to the script, and the `echo "hello"` command will be executed and print `hello` onto the screen.

Comment: Would would $1 be in my shell script?

Comment: If you don't pass a command line argument, then it's a blank string.

Comment: Well, I'm running it through NSTask and it seems like it's freezing my code unless I put an argument. I put "H". It errored: "Could not find "H"!" I'm confused...

Comment: Looks like you have to have Jetty and MySQL running.  Do you?

Comment: "Seems like" - how do you know?

Answer (score 0):

Just for the curious, here's the entire code environment for the shell script called server.sh:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/charliebot/

Some more information can be found here:

```
# http://www.alicebot.org/resources/programd/readme.html
# http://www.noendpress.com/caleb/ALICE101_MacOSX/
```

Comment: Yep! This is what I'm trying to run.